# Iterating over and adding to an array in RxSwift

Tags: for-loop, iteration, rx-swift

I am making a network request from which I am getting a bunch of users, I am also given a emailDetails object that holds the userId property as well. I am trying to iterate over the users coming from the network request to match up all of the userIds from the emailDetails

I am not sure how to iterate, I know enumerated exists in RxSwift.

```
self.emailRecipients = networkRequestToGetUser
            .asObservable()
            .map { users in users.filter {$0.userId == 
             emailDetails.userIds }.first }
            .map {correctUsers in return correctUsers?.email}
            .unwrap()
```

Error I'm getting: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and '[String]'

Comment: Here is the answer that worked for me.   self.emailRecipients = networkRequestUsers
            .asObservable()
            .map { $0.filter { $0.userId == emailDetails.userIds } }
            .map { $0.map { $0.email } }
            .unwrap()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I understand your code snippet, your issue is not actually related to RxSwift. Apparently `emailDetails.userIds` is an Array of Strings `[String]`. You could check if the Array contains the `userId` using this as you mapping instead:

```
    .map { users in users.filter { emailDetails.userIds.contains($0.userId) }.first }
```

to get the first match. If you want all of them in an Array, just drop the  `.first` and map to the email field:

```
self.emailRecipients = networkRequestToGetUser
        .asObservable()
        .map { users in 
            users.filter {
                emailDetails.userIds.contains($0.userId)
            }.map { $0.email } 
        }
```

to get a Observable of an Array of email addresses. To get the actual adresses, don't forget to `subscribe()` to that `emailRecipients`-Observable.